# Videos of TeX Users Group 2018 conference talks are online!

Tags: discussion, community, tug, conferences

[image]

The TeX Users Group 2018 annual conference was held in Rio de Janeiro (at the mathematics institute called IMPA) in July. Many TeX.SE users participated and even gave talks there. You can watch videos of the talks online now!

- [**YouTube channel of IMPA**](https://www.youtube.com/user/impabr/videos)
- [**Conference program/schedule**](https://www.tug.org/tug2018/program.html)
- [**Dedicated TeX.SE chat room**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80267/tug2018)

Enjoy, everyone!

Comment: The videos are on youtube now: https://www.youtube.com/user/impabr/videos

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks a lot!

Comment: Our lion friend looks particularly splendid in this drawing!